# Don't see Code Signing Identity List in xcode 4.0.2?

Tags: xcode4

My XCode Version is 4.0.2, 
How to configure XCode 4.0.2 show Code Signing Identity Dropbox List ?

[image: a Demo]

Is it a Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be an bug in Xcode 4.

I just typed in the exact name from Keychain Access (in bold at the top of the preview window) and everything worked OK.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode Go to Editors>Show Values,This will solves the problem